# Transferring resources from one project to another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, resources

I had to create my project from scratch, but I would still like to copy the resources from the old project to the new one.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

I have seen that I can import a .resx file, I guess that might be one way to transfer these resources over, but I haven't found a way to export a .resx file.

I can click a single file and Choose "Select for export", but I have like 50 files in my project, and I don't wanto to export them one by one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I navigate to the folder where the resources of the old projects are stored (right-click an existing resource and select "Go to destination folder").
Copy these to a new folder on the desktop.
In the new project, click "Add Resource"->"Existing" and open the files.